# I can authorize users but cant redirect them to member page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have designed a login page for my plugin it perfectly works and check the users credentials but when the user is authorized I cant move to the px_member234.php page.

the first page is px_myplugin234.php then it opens the px_login234.php file using include(px_login234.php) which is used for authentication, I suppose thats why the header does not work. is there any other option?

```
<form method="post" action="">
    ....
 </form>

 authorizer(){
  ........
  if(user_is_authorized)
    {
       //go to member.php page
       header ("Location:px_member234.php");  << does not work

    }
 }
```

I have also used the following but it does not work

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location="px_member234.php";</script>'; 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="px_member234.php";</script>';
```

Comment: use `header("Location:member.php");`?

Comment: @Philipp, does not work

Comment: what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @Philipp, it does not move to member.php just stays on current page

Comment: Just for the record you have your header call commented out.

Comment: @anditpainsme, my typo thanks but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're echoing HTML content before the header.

When PHP sees actual output, it has to flush all of it heads to apache (who sends them to the client). After PHP has sent the headers and started output, it is *not possible* to add more headers.

Your code needs to be refactored to call `header('Location: ...')` BEFORE outputting any content at all

Answer (score 2):

You can use header redirection. To use this, you have to ensure, that nothing is outputed before the header command. If the header is already sent, this code wont work

```
header("Location:member.php");
```

In your example, the auth code have to be on the top of the page. If you can't prevent the output before your header function call, you could still add a meta redirect header to the html page or use JavaScript to set a new `window.location`

Comment: the first page is px_myplugin234.php then it opens the px_login234.php file which is used for authentication, I suppose thats why the header does not work. is there any other option?

Comment: Use firebug/ie developer tools and tell us the error Output(Hit F12 key)

Answer (score 1):

Besides calling the `header()` function before any output like others mentioned to the page you should also leave a space between `Location:` and the URL.

What you have:

```
header("Location:member.php");
```

What will work:

```
header("Location: member.php");
```

### **Update**

Try and include the full URI instead of your relative one as per [HTTP/1.1 Header Field Definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).

From php.net:

HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `dirname()` to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Try it without a space. It doesn't work, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

To your form markup, you can add

```
<form method="post" action="?noheader=true">.
```

The ?noheader=true will stop Wordpress from outputting any headers.  You can see details here: http://www.lessthanweb.com/blog/wordpress-and-wp_redirect-function-problem

Also, in wordpress development, wp_redirect is preferred over the php header function because it includes hooks that let it play nicely with other plugins.

Note that it takes the absolute url of where you want to redirect the user.  Since you're making a plugin, you can use get_option('siteurl') to get the root url so:

```
<?php 
     wp_redirect(get_option('siteurl').'px_member234.php');
     exit;
?>
```

Comment: It is not a website it is a plugin.